# How do I keep DEP from killing my JITted exception handler?

Tags: windows, delphi, compiler-construction, exception, jit

I'm working on a JIT compiler that seems to work fine so far, except for one problem: when the code raises an exception and the exception handler is in a JITted routine, the OS immediately kills the process.  This does not happen when I turn off DEP, so I assume it's DEP-related.

When DEP is turned off, the exception handler runs correctly, and I made sure to call `VirtualProtect` on the JITted routine with a protection value of `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`, and then verify it with `VirtualQuery`.

Testing this under a debugger reports that the fatal error happens at the point where the exception is raised, not later, which I assume means something like this is happening:

- Exception is raised
- SEH looks for nearest exception handler
- SEH sees that nearest exception handler is in JITted code and immediately freaks out
- Windows kills the task

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong, and how I can get DEP to accept my exception handler?  It doesn't have any problem executing the JITted code itself.

**EDIT:** Here's the Delphi code that generates the stub.  It allocates memory, loads basic code, fixes up fixups for jumps and try blocks, and then marks the memory as executable. This is part of the work in progress for the external function JIT on the [DWS](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/) project.

```
function MakeExecutable(const value: TBytes; const calls: TFunctionCallArray; call: pointer;
   const tryFrame: TTryFrame): pointer;
var
   oldprotect: cardinal;
   lCall, lOffset: nativeInt;
   ptr: pointer;
   fixup: TFunctionCall;
   info: _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
begin
   result := VirtualAlloc(nil, length(value), MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
   system.Move(value[0], result^, length(value));
   for fixup in calls do
   begin
      ptr := @PByte(result)[fixup.offset];
      if fixup.call = 0 then
         lCall := nativeInt(call)
      else lCall := fixup.call;
      lOffset := (lCall - NativeInt(ptr)) - sizeof(pointer);
      PNativeInt(ptr)^ := lOffset;
   end;
   if tryFrame[0] <> 0 then
   begin
      ptr := @PByte(result)[tryFrame[0]];
      if PPointer(ptr)^ <> nil then
         asm int 3 end;
      PPointer(ptr)^ := @PByte(result)[tryFrame[2] - 1];

      ptr := @PByte(result)[tryFrame[1]];
      if PPointer(ptr)^ <> nil then
         asm int 3 end;
      PPointer(ptr)^ := @PByte(result)[tryFrame[3]];
   end;

   if not VirtualProtect(result, length(value), PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, oldProtect) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
   VirtualQuery(result, info, sizeof(info));
   if info.Protect <> PAGE_EXECUTE_READ then
      raise Exception.Create('VirtualProtect failed');
end;
```

To reproduce the problem:

- Check out the latest version of DWS from SVN
- Build LanguageTests.exe in the \test folder
- Disable all tests, then enable the one at the bottom of the list, under the heading `dwsExternalFunctionTests`.
- Run the tester.  If DEP is off, it should work.  If DEP is on, it will crash as described.

**EDIT 2:** Here is a dump of the generated machine code routine in question:

```
//preamble
02870000 55               push ebp
02870001 89E5             mov ebp,esp
02870003 83C4F4           add esp,-$0c
02870006 51               push ecx
02870007 53               push ebx
02870008 56               push esi
02870009 57               push edi
0287000A 8BDA             mov ebx,edx
0287000C 8B33             mov esi,[ebx]
0287000E 31C0             xor eax,eax
//setup exception frame
02870010 55               push ebp
02870011 685D008702       push $0287005d
02870016 64FF30           push dword ptr fs:[eax]
02870019 648920           mov fs:[eax],esp
//procedure body
0287001C 31C9             xor ecx,ecx
0287001E 894DF8           mov [ebp-$08],ecx
02870021 8B06             mov eax,[esi]
02870023 8B5308           mov edx,[ebx+$08]
02870026 8B38             mov edi,[eax]
02870028 FF5710           call dword ptr [edi+$10]
0287002B 8945FC           mov [ebp-$04],eax
0287002E 8B4604           mov eax,[esi+$04]
02870031 8B5308           mov edx,[ebx+$08]
02870034 8D4DF8           lea ecx,[ebp-$08]
02870037 8B38             mov edi,[eax]
02870039 FF571C           call dword ptr [edi+$1c]
//call to a native routine. This routine raises an exception
0287003C 8B55F8           mov edx,[ebp-$08]
0287003F 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
02870042 E8CD1FE6FD       call TestStringExc
//cleanup
02870047 31C0             xor eax,eax
02870049 5A               pop edx
0287004A 59               pop ecx
0287004B 59               pop ecx
//exception handler: a try/finally block to clean
//up a string variable used in the body of the code
0287004C 648910           mov fs:[eax],edx
0287004F 6864008702       push $02870064
02870054 8D45F8           lea eax,[ebp-$08]
02870057 E86870B9FD       call @UStrClr
0287005C C3               ret 
0287005D E98666B9FD       jmp @HandleFinally
02870062 EBF0             jmp $02870054
//more cleanup
02870064 5F               pop edi
02870065 5E               pop esi
02870066 5B               pop ebx
02870067 59               pop ecx
02870068 8BE5             mov esp,ebp
0287006A 5D               pop ebp
0287006B C3               ret
```

This is designed to be equivalent (if not identical) to the following Delphi code:

```
function Stub(const args: TExprBaseListExec): Variant;
var
   list: PObjectTightList;
   a: integer;
   b: string;
   //use of a string variable will introduce an implicit try-finally
   //block by the compiler to handle cleanup
begin
   list := args.List;
   a := TExprBase(args[0]).EvalAsInteger(args.exec);
   TExprBase(args[1]).EvalAsString(args.exec, b);
   TestStringExc(a, b);
end;
```

The purpose of the TestStringExc routine is to raise an exception and ensure that the exception handler correctly cleans up the string.

Comment: I had a similar problems in a Detours unit. I found out that it is not enough to call VirtualProtect. You also have to call VirtualAlloc before that too. And it also states that: "All pages in the specified region must be within the same reserved region allocated when calling the VirtualAlloc or VirtualAllocEx function using MEM_RESERVE". But I admit that this may not be it as do not know enough on this subject to be any expert.

Comment: @Runner: The memory in question has been allocated with `VirtualAlloc`, with flags `MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT`.

Comment: Ok then it is not that. I have it called with MEM_COMMIT and PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE flags. If it is not that then check if the memory is in the protected region. After that I have no more advice :(

Comment: Is the code x86 or x64?

Comment: To be complete. This is the call: VirtualAlloc(nil,TrampolineSize,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); And the protect is also called with PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE I am sure they must match

Comment: @Runner: No, changing it that way doesn't fix it. :(

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's x86.

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: One thing I see is that you are not checking to make sure `VirtualAlloc()` succeeds before using the `Result`. Other than that, can you please show the contents of `calls` and `tryFrame`, since you are using those to fill in the contents of the allocated memory, so lets make sure those contain valid x86 instructions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: if VirtualAlloc was failing, the next line (the `Move` call) would fail with an AV.  It doesn't.  And posting the code responsible for generating this content would be a *massive* addition to my post, but if you want to see it, it's checked in to the DWS project.  The code above is from the unit `dwsExternalFunctions`.  The generated machine code itself is valid and works as expected when DEP is turned off, and also works as expected when DEP is turned on as long as no exceptions are raised.  I'm just trying to figure out why exceptions are triggering DEP in this specific case.

Comment: I just added the generated code, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Looking at your comment again, I realized something I had missed the first time I read it.  Just to clarify, the contents of `calls` and `tryFrame` don't contain "valid x86 instructions;" those have already all been generated.  What those arguments hold are *memory addresses*, fixups whose final values aren't known until after code generation is complete because they're relative to the location in memory of the generated code itself.

Comment: Why don't you check for errors?

Comment: @David: What are you talking about? As I've pointed out, this problem comes from an automated test failing.  "Checking for errors" is exactly what I'm doing here.  Or do you mean "check the return value of VirtualAlloc"?  Because, as I pointed out to Remy, that's implicit in the next line, and if I'm out of memory, I have bigger problems anyway.  Either way, it has nothing to do with DEP and SEH.

Comment: You should check for errors properly, not throw AVs.

Comment: @David: Perhaps, but again, **this is not relevant to DEP and SEH**.  Changing the error checking on the call to `VirtualAlloc` will not fix the problem I am having here.

Comment: I know. I'm just whining about your code more generally. I don't like code that doesn't check for errors. Win32Check is all you need. Why don't you look at the Mono jitter and see that does?

Comment: @David: Because there's no good way to handle being out of memory.  Your program is dead at that point, and it really just boils down to how you send out the announcement.  That's what I mean by "you have bigger problems."  Either way, an exception will be raised, and the stack trace will make the location of the failure immediately obvious to anyone who knows how to read a stack trace. :P  (And anyone who doesn't won't be able to do anything about it anyway.)  As for looking at the Mono jitter, I suppose I could try that, though I don't have any familiarity with it...

Comment: Actually out of memory can be handled. Plenty of systems can manage that. For your use case, giving up is reasonable. That said, an out of memory error would mean more to the user than AV. Finding an extant jitter that gets stack based exceptions right would be how I would tackle this problem. Yes, getting on top of Mono will take time.

Comment: Is SafeSEH an issue here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: AFAIK no Delphi compiler supports SafeSEH yet. I'm certain that XE didn't, which is what I'm using.

Comment: Or perhaps SEHOP. Is your host executable built with Delphi? Did you look at Mono yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: SEHOP is not enabled on this system.  I looked at "Mini," the JIT compiler for Mono, it either does Win32 SEH very differently from Delphi or I'm looking in the wrong place, as I haven't found anything that emits code dealing with the FS register.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's quite possible that it does not do SEH. Nobody says that exception handling has to be built on top of SEH. But hey, what do I know?!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The code at https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/a31c107f59298053e4ff17fd09b2fa617b75c1ba/mono/mini/exceptions-x86.c uses the terms SEH and Win32_SEH a handful of times.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Where exactly does it error out? - if you run it outside the IDE you should get an entry in the event log with the address. Perhaps you already said so somewhere - I only just noticed this question and there's a lot here to take in. FWIW, I have done stuff where I reorganize code in memory at run-time, including exception handling blocks, and it works fine, so there must be something specific to how it is being done here. I did not see any obvious mistakes above, though.

Comment: Eventually you have to register your functions to windows using the [RtlAddFunctionTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api. It seems win64 exception handling is way more restrictive when it comes to checking were the exception occured.

Comment: @mrabat: This is 32-bit code.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: MSDN Says it's for 64bit....

Comment: I know that it won't fix problem with DEP and raising an exception from generated code, but I think that you should call `FlushInstructionCache` as docs says for `VirtualAlloc` (at bottom of page).

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Did you ever get this resolved? I am curious because I now face the same problem in some code patching that I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

The following code might help (which coms from my own compiler for stubbing interfaces:

```
function GetExecutableMem(Size: Integer): Pointer;
  procedure RaiseOutofMemory;
  begin
    raise EOutOfResources.Create('UnitProxyGenerator.GetExecutableMem: Out of memory error.');
  end;
var
  LastCommitTop: PChar;
begin
  // We round the memory needed up to 16 bytes which seems to be a cache line amound on the P4.
  Size := (Size + $F) and (not $F);
  //
  Result := MemUsed;
  Inc(MemUsed, Size);
  // Do we need to commit some more memory?
  if MemUsed > MemCommitTop then begin
    // Do we need more mem than we reserved initially?
    if MemUsed > MemTop then RaiseOutOfMemory;
    // Try to commit the memory requested.
    LastCommitTop := MemCommitTop;
    MemCommitTop := PChar((Longword(MemUsed) + (SystemInfo.dwPageSize - 1)) and (not (SystemInfo.dwPageSize - 1)));
    if not Assigned(VirtualAlloc(LastCommitTop, MemCommitTop - LastCommitTop, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)) then RaiseOutOfMemory;
  end;
end;

initialization
  GetSystemInfo(SystemInfo);
  MemBase := VirtualAlloc(nil, MemSize, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
  if MemBase = nil then Halt; // VERY BAD ...
  MemUsed := MemBase;
  MemCommitTop := MemBase;
  MemTop := MemBase + MemSize;
finalization
  VirtualFree(MemBase, MemSize, MEM_DECOMMIT);
  VirtualFree(MemBase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
end.
```

Please note the PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE in the VirtualAlloc call.

When process is run DEP enabled the following runs correctly:

```
type
  TTestProc = procedure( out A: Integer ); stdcall;

procedure Encode( var P: PByte; Code: array of Byte ); overload;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High( Code ) do begin
    P^ := Code[ i ];
    Inc( P );
  end;
end;

procedure Encode( var P: PByte; Code: Integer ); overload;
begin
  PInteger( P )^ := Code;
  Inc( P, sizeof( Integer ) );
end;

procedure Encode( var P: PByte; Code: Pointer ); overload;
begin
  PPointer( P )^ := Code;
  Inc( P, sizeof( Pointer ) );
end;

// returns address where exceptiuon handler will be.
function EncodeTry( var P: PByte ): PByte;
begin
  Encode( P, [ $33, $C0, $55,$68 ] );             // xor eax,eax; push ebp; push @handle
  Result := P;
  Encode( P, nil );
  Encode( P, [ $64, $FF, $30, $64, $89, $20 ] );  // push dword ptr fs:[eax]; mov fs:[eax],esp
end;

procedure EncodePopTry( var P: PByte );
begin
  Encode( P, [ $33, $C0, $5A, $59, $59, $64, $89, $10 ] );  // xor eax,eax; pop edx; pop ecx; pop ecx; mov fs:[eax],edx
end;

function Delta( P, Q: PByte ): Integer;
begin
  Result := Integer( P ) - Integer( Q );
end;

function GetHandleFinally(): pointer;
asm
  lea eax, system.@HandleFinally
end;

procedure TForm10.Button5Click( Sender: TObject );
var
  P, Q, R, S, T: PByte;
  A:             Integer;
begin
  P := VirtualAlloc( nil, $10000, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE );
  if not Assigned( P ) then Exit;
  try

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Equivalent
    //
    // A:=10;
    // try
    //   A:=20
    //   PInteger(nil)^:=20
    // finally
    //   A:=30;
    // end;
    // A:=40;
    //
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Stack frame
    Q := P;
    Encode( Q, [ $55, $8B, $EC ] );                  // push ebp, mov ebp, esp

    // A := 10;
    Encode( Q, [ $8B, $45, $08, $C7, $00 ] );
    Encode( Q, 10 );                                 // mov eax,[ebp+$08], mov [eax],<int32>

    // try
    R := EncodeTry( Q );

    // TRY CODE !!!!
    // A := 20;
    Encode( Q, [ $8B, $45, $08, $C7, $00 ] );
    Encode( Q, 20 );                                 // mov eax,[ebp+$08], mov [eax],<int32>

    // REMOVE THIS AND NO EXCEPTION WILL OCCUR.
    Encode( Q, [ $33, $C0, $C7, $00 ] );             // EXCEPTION: xor eax, eax, mov [eax], 20
    Encode( Q, 20 );
    // END OF REMOVE

    // END OF TRY CODE


    EncodePopTry( Q );
    Encode( Q, [ $68 ] );                            // push @<afterfinally>
    S := Q;
    Encode( Q, nil );

    // FINALLY CODE!!!!
    T := Q;
    // A := 30;
    Encode( Q, [ $8B, $45, $08, $C7, $00 ] );
    Encode( Q, 30 );                                 // mov eax,[ebp+$08], mov [eax],<int32>

    // AFter finally
    Encode( Q, [ $C3 ] );                            // ret
    Encode( R, Q );                                  // Fixup try

    // SEH handler
    Encode( Q, [ $E9 ] );                            // jmp
    Encode( Q, Delta( GetHandleFinally(), Q ) - sizeof( Pointer ) ); // <diff:i32>
    Encode( Q, [ $E9 ] );                            // jmp
    Encode( Q, Delta( T, Q ) - sizeof( Pointer ) );  // <diff:i32>

    // After SEH frame
    Encode( S, Q );
    // A := 40;
    Encode( Q, [ $8B, $45, $08, $C7, $00 ] );
    Encode( Q, 40 );                             // mov eax,[ebp+$08], mov [eax],<int32>

    // pop stack frame
    Encode( Q, [ $5D, $C2, $04, $00 ] );         // pop ebp, ret 4

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // And.... execute
    A := 0;
    try
      TTestProc( P )( A );
    except
      ;
    end;
    Caption := IntToStr( A )+'!1';


    // Dofferent protection... execute
    VirtualProtect( P, $10000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, nil );

    A := 0;
    try
      TTestProc( P )( A );
    except
      ;
    end;
    Caption := IntToStr( A ) + '!2';

  finally
    // Cleanup
    VirtualFree( P, $10000, MEM_RELEASE );
  end;
end;
```

It works on Windows 7 with both DEP disabled and enabled and seems to be a minimal piece of "JIT code" with a Delphi try-finally block in it. Could it be that it is a problem with a different / newer Windows platform?

Comment: SEH seems to work with EXECUTE READWRITE here. I did not test with EXECUTE_READ. The code is used for Win32 not Win64 (it's approx 10 years old) and SEH works very differently in WIn64.

Comment: Nope. Changing it from `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` doesn't fix it.  This is Win32 code.

Comment: Running your updated sample under Windows 7 Pro, SP1, with DEP active, the exception inside the JITted stub kills the process.  Not sure what the difference is between your system and mine, but it's having the same problem as my code.

Comment: @Mason: I just discovered the difference and it's my bad: I did have a different unit in my application linked in and it did a SetProcessDEPPolicy( 0 );. Apparently they "solved" the same problem this way. I now see that with DEP enabled ( 1 ) in the call the problem persists and with DEP disabled ( 0 ) the problem is gone. The problem has definitely something to do with a DEP enabled feature, most likely something like SafeSEH.

Comment: I tried that, and it proves an effective workaround.  It would still be nice to find a way to actually fix the problem, though.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Your problem lies in Ntdll.RtlIsValidHandler which validates exception handler images when it's dispatching exceptions.  If you use the method I described and register a Vectored Exception Handler you can do your own exception dispatching and avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted my other post and believe I realize what your problem probably is.

The issue lies in ntdll.RtlIsValidHandler which is validating your exception handler when its dispatching exceptions according to SAFESEH.

You need to avoid this by registering a Vectored Exception Handler and do your own exception dispatching so you wont have to worry about this behavior at all.

Edit:
I believe your underlying issue is that the ExecuteDispatchEnable and ImageDispatchEnable are being set in the kernel's KPROCESS structure for some reason by DEP which is why you are having this problem to begin with. It might be possible to set these by calling NtSetInformationProcess, but given that this is not officially documented I cannot give good insight on how to make this call.

Comment: Thanks, but SafeSEH is not enabled for this process.

Comment: I think using a vectored handler may end up being your solution regardless as it bypasses some of the OS logistics and gives you more immediate control.

Comment: All right. How do I set that up, and how do I make sure that it only applies to my JITted code and doesn't interfere with the existing Delphi exception handling in the host application?  If you can answer those two questions with a workable solution, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: You would have to make sure that you can record where you would be using the handler in the code so that you can properly either dispatch the exception to your handler and return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION thus not passing the exception, or you would return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH which would pass it to the normal exception handling chain.

Comment: Yes, but as I said in response to your earlier question, this is all outside my area of expertise.  Right now I'm understanding about half of what you're saying, but I don't know how to register a vectored exception handler or do any of the stuff you're talking about here.  Can you post a working code sample that I can use to fix this problem?

Comment: The best I can do is refer you to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I wish I could post a complete answer with full code but I've never used VEH handlers in Delphi, and a full solution which does what I described is not exactly a small amount of code.

Comment: I think your main issue is that the ExecuteDispatchEnable and ImageDispatchEnable are being set in the kernel's KPROCESS structure for some reason by DEP which is why you are having this problem to begin with.  It might be possible to set these by calling NtSetInformationProcess, but given that this is not officially documented I cannot give good insight on how to make this call.

Comment: I'm sorry, but looking over VEH stuff I'm not seeing anything about how it would solve my problem.  A VEH appears to be about giving some other code a first crack at handling *any exception,* for example to report it to a debugger.  What I need is to make the current SEH chain work correctly at a specific point at which the system breaks down, and I don't see anything explaining how a VEH can help with that.

Comment: Yes sorry, I will try to explain how I have done something similar in the past in C++.  If the exception is related to just a function you can use the function pointer and the following function pointer to determine the size of the function so you can check the EIP of the exception.  You can also use goto style labels which you can use to get the location of any directly following instruction to create ranges for your exceptions.  Basically if the EIP of the exception in the VEH is any of your chosen ranges you would pass the exception to your associated handler.  I hope this makes sense

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47895/discussion-between-nowayz-and-mason-wheeler)